# Need help understanding equivalence relation problems

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

I have a few questions regarding equivalence relations, but I don't really know how to answer them. If someone could solve and explain these two (or one) questions, it would be much appreciated.

Let P1 = {B0, B1, B2} be a partition of Z, where
B0 = {3n|n ∈ Z}, B1 = {3n + 1|n ∈ Z}, and B2 = {3n + 2|n ∈ Z}. Describe the equivalence relation R1 corresponding to P1.

Let S be the set of ternary strings and let R be an equivalence relation on S. Suppose the collection of equivalence classes for R is P = {Bi|i ∈ N}, where a representative of Bi
is 222...2, a ternary string of length i consisting only of twos. Describe the equivalence relation R.

Comment: What did you try? Can you define what an equivalence relation is? A partition? I can't really help here since any help is essentially giving you the answer here.

Comment: @DonThousand I literally have no idea what to do, which is why I posted something asking for help

Comment: As you have no idea what to do, the place to start is to look up the definitions of the words you are using: partition, equivalence relation, ternary string, equivalence class, representative. Once you know what those worda mean, you may find that you are able to do the problems on your own. If you still need help after learning what the words mean, come back, tell us what the words mean, and what progress you made toward solutions, and where you got stuck, and we'll be able to give you better help.

Comment: Making any progress, Jackson?

Comment: I guess you've lost interest. Too bad.